# Create windows executable shortcuts for given bash commands

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash, shortcut

In Windows, I'd like to create files that, once executed, launches a series of bash commands. This would be to reduce time for opening my dev projects and my IDE. In summary, I'd like to:

- Open Git Bash
- `cd` to specific folders
- Launch my IDE (here it's IntelliJ Webstorm, launchable with `webstorm64.exe .`

I don't care about the file format - I'm just trying to put this simply (preferably without downloading specific compilers) but I have no knowledge about this kind of files and processes...